# A Beginner and the Problem with the 50 Reputations Requirement

Tags: support, comment, reputation, new-users, privileges

I have just started studying calculus and sometimes have questions which are super easy for the most members of the site.
I had a question and did not want to ask it because a similar one was already on the website. So I tried to ask my question in a comment under that similar question but I needed 50 reputations. If I could ask my question and ask for some clarification everything would be OK. But now there is only one way for me: to post it as a new question. But my questions get closed because they are repetitive or because of lack of clarity and details, despite my efforts to be as clear as possible. I get negative scores because of this and lose reputation.
Even this very question has been asked before but I was not able to comment. It seems I'm stuck in a cycle.

Comment: I would suggest you to answer some of the questions which you understand and with two to three upvotes you would be able to comment(Well, thats what I did).

Comment: You have enough reputation to [talk in chat](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).  For new users having difficulty asking good Questions, or with understanding some existing posts, the [Constructive Feedback chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) seems like a starting point.

Comment: @Kavesh I have upvoted your questions because they are well-written. You should now have enough reputation to comment!

Comment: Some related older posts: [How to make a remark when reputation is under 50?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9203), [Should we really have a reputation requirement for commenting?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12228) and [Is this an answer only site for people who just started here?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19454) (There are probably more similar discussions - and even more on [meta.se] or Meta Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Asking your question in a comment on an older question probably wouldn't do you much good. No one would see it there except for the user who posted the original question, and even that user might no longer be active on the site. Better to post a new question, linking to the older one, and explaining exactly why you feel your question isn't a duplicate.